# How to catch the developer after the build failed in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using `Jenkins` as Continuous Integration Tool. I found a challenge while working with Jenkins.

General build process: Developer(s) checkin the source code into repository.

a. If there were errors during build, the developer that checked in needs to be identified and he/she needs to be notified. Developer can then check the cause, fix it and check back in. Build manager will then run script to see if it fixed or if the error was still lurking.

b. If there were no error, build manager could pass on to `QA team` for testing after which the code base would go live.

Challenges : Is there anyway/Plugin to catch the developer who broke the Build.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check here [15 Plugins that every Jenkins installation should include](http://www.blackbuild.com/15-must-have-plugins-for-jenkins/)

Comment: Thanks Sebrii Zouhaier. I found the solution.

Comment: Please post your solution to help others